# QuickLook Plugin: how does it work when 2 plugins handle the same file type?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, quicklook

If a user has 2 or more quicklook plugins that handle the same kMDItemContentType what happens? Which plugin gets priority to do that actual work? Can that be set programmatically?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I am interested on the answer too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a quick reading of the docs ([Installing Quick Look Generators](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005020-CH4-SW4)), the Quick Look daemon chooses a generator based on the following search order:

1. Inside the app bundle: `MyApp.app/Content/Library/QuickLook`
2. In `~/Library/QuickLook`
3. In `/Library/QuickLook`
4. In `/System/Library/QuickLook`

They finish by saying that if there is more than one generator for a UTI, the one that ranks highest on that list is chosen. If there are two or more for the same UTI at the same level, Apple says there is no way to know which will be chosen; the generator that is found first in their search is used.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I couldn't find that. I did look but must have missed that bit. That actually works just how I would want it.

Comment: Glad I could help! They buried that section at the end of the section. It probably would have gone better in the 'Overview of Generator Implementation' section.

Answer (score 0):

I've found you can modify the `Info.plist` file within a `.qlgenerator` plugin and remove a UTI entry from `UTImportedTypeDeclarations` to force Quicklook to use another generator for that UTI.  You may need to run `qlmanage -r` afterward for changes to take effect.